# change progress bar into double

Tags: android, android-progressbar

PROGRESS BAR:

```
ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
pb.setProgress(0);
int k = (int)max;
pb.setMax(k);
int j = (int)(cost);
pb.setProgress(j);
```

this code for a progress bar that only take an int value i want to change the code to take a double value

Comment: does it make any sense to have a progressbar with double?

Comment: If you want higher resolution in the progress bar, you still use integers, but use setMax() to a value greater than the default 100 to increase resolution.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The `ProgressBar` widget only accepts `ints` for its max and current progress. You can't control the minimum, as it is always `0`.

You could multiply your required maximum and current progress values by a power of 10, such that the decimal goes away. The `ProgressBar` will still show the same amount of progress as it would with a decimal value, as the progress is a ratio of `currentValue/maxValue`. As you'll be multiplying both by the same number, the ratios are equal. For example:

```
0.1/10 = 0.01
```

However, if you multiple both 0.1 and 10 by 10 to get rid of the decimal, you get:

```
1/100 = 0.01 //Same result
```

Comment: @user2166562 Uh, just keep multiplying your double values until you've gotten rid of the decimal. You'll only run into problems if your final value exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE, but that's over 2 billion so I doubt you'll hit it.

Comment: You can also just use `Math.round(double)` to get an int value.

Answer (score 1):

It accept only integer value. There is no `method` for that to pass the double value.

```
public synchronized void setProgress (int progress)
```

Look android developer docs.

```
Parameters
progress    the new progress, between 0 and getMax()
```