# Progressbar showing values in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

### I have a `progressbar` that i have defined for accepting the rating

```
RATINGbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.RATINGseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        RATINGbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                RATINGtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RATINGtextViewProgressID);
                RATINGtextProgress.setText("Rating:: "+progress);
                seekBar.setMax(5); 


            }
        });
```

---

### This Bar accepts maximum of 5 number as i have defined !

- when i  select it and scroll horizontally, it accepts values as
  `1-2-3-4-5`
- How to make the progress bar take values like
  `1`-`1.5`-`2`-`2.5`-`3`-`3.5`-`4`-`4.5`-`5`
- what changes should i need to make here

How to make my progress bar accept values in interval of `0.5`

**Hope i am clear**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make my progress bar accept values in interval of 0.5

Short answer:

You can't. ProgressBar takes only **int values** for actual and max progress and you can't change this behaviour. This how it's designated by OS.

**Update:** Look also at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418571/change-progress-bar-into-double).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `ProgressBar` intervals to float. Instead, try using `RatingBar`.

Comment: Is it possible to customise ratingBar to look like a progressBar ?